# Extract json data inside array to rows in Spark

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working with Azure Databricks to parse over a large number of small (4kb) JSON files containing information from a remote monitoring station with the following schema:

```
root
 |-- Body: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- telemetry: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- temp: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- bankNumber: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- measurementTime: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- measurementType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- sensorNumber: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- tempatureReading: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- wind: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- measurementTime: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- measurementType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- sensorNumber: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- velocityReading: double (nullable = true)
 |-- EnqueuedTimeUtc: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SystemProperties: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- connectionAuthMethod: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- connectionDeviceGenerationId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- connectionDeviceId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- contentEncoding: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- contentType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- enqueuedTime: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- messageId: string (nullable = true)
```

The schema was auto generated when I did the initial `read.json()` and correctly matches my JSON files.

My issue is in trying to get the data contained within the `Body.telemetry.temp` and `Body.telemetry.wind` arrays to be in the correct form. I've tried a couple of different ways to go about getting it to display correctly but nothing has worked. I am trying to get it to look like this (columns):

```
|Measurement Type|Bank Number|Sensor Number|Temperature Measurement|Measurement Time|
```

I tried using a series of daisy chained functions of this form:

```
.withColumon(<alias>, explode("Body.telemetry.temp.measurementTime"))
```

This gave me the result I was looking for at first, it was unpacking the data into rows. However the resulting table still contained a copy of `Body` as a full string and when I tried this with all the parts of the temp structs it just kept running out of memory on Azure.

I tried playing around with `.select()` functions quite a bit but was never able to get more then one row working (using `explode`).

I've been googling around for a good number of hours and just can't seem to find anything that seems 100% applicable or something that works. The few solutions I did find that seemed like they may work were in scala which I do not know (I'd like to stick to python for the moment if possible).

Comment: Did you try to drop the original column `Body` with `df.drop("Body")`?

Comment: Yeah, when I tried dropping that column it dropped all of the columns that were being accessed through it which includes the temp and wind arrays that contain the data I was after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your `printSchema` output, the `body`, `telemetry` and `element` are structs whereas `temp` is an array. So you need to work on that first.Below are the samples you can test it out.

```
    df = spark.read.json("./test_data.json") 
    df.printSchema()
    df2=df.select(explode(df.temp))
    df.show()

##-OR
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.withColumn("temp",F.explode(F.col("temp"))).select("temp.*").show()
```

Please post a sample json file and progress you have done in case of any concern with the code snippet

Comment: Thank you a ton!. The bottom solution using pyspark.sql worked perfectly for me but I wasn't able to get the solution using just select to work.

Comment: Happy to provide the solution.I would need sample dataof yours to test it.