# Get value from Spark dataframe when rows are dictionaries

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, data-extraction

I have a PySpark dataframe that looks like this:

| Values | Column |
| --- | --- |
| {[0.0, 54.04, 48.... | Sector A |
| {[0.0, 55.4800000... | Sector A |

If I show the first element of the column 'Values' without truncating the data, it looks like this:

> {[0.0, 54.04, 48.19, 68.59, 61.81, 54.730000000000004, 48.51, 57.03,
> 59.49, 55.44, 60.56, 52.52, 51.44, 55.06, 55.27, 54.61, 55.89, 56.5, 45.4, 68.63, 63.88, 48.25, 57.19, 50.69, 48.75, 48.69, 53.17, 54.84, 49.04, 57.53, 56.14, 61.13, 57.26, 62.050000000000004, 53.96, 63.28, 57.99, 53.95, 58.69, 53.94, 46.86, 54.31, 59.15, 53.57, 50.22, 60.02, 58.04, 47.39, 53.64, 63.95, 66.87, 63.49, 57.120000000000005, 58.09, 53.870000000000005, 59.84, 50.910000000000004, 53.75, 56.730000000000004, 55.89, 49.43, 57.47, 53.25, 63.99, 50.85, 51.25, 52.83, 52.36, 63.4, 48.78, 50.85, 55.18, 51.28, 52.11, 53.72, 62.14, 55.75, 53.17, 62.07, 55.11, 57.26, 54.76, 53.19, 58.32, 55.4, 62.5, 61.04, 47.730000000000004, 63.46, 53.24, 55.6, 59.34, 56.870000000000005, 48.120000000000005, 52.0, 51.870000000000005, 55.08, 47.45, 55.01, 54.29, 55.1, 54.660000000000004, 55.85, 63.22, 47.89, 58.910000000000004, 57.88, 61.52, 60.72, 59.46, 50.120000000000005, 57.99, 64.64, 56.28, 49.82, 50.79, 50.44, 47.550000000000004, 59.35, 50.03, 63.42, 56.7, 62.550000000000004, 60.17, 55.19, 53.64, 53.65, 57.78, 53.120000000000005, 47.31, 57.39, 56.18, 62.76, 57.39, 51.93, 57.53, 59.71, 51.06, 58.31, 55.81, 56.18, 62.33, 71.91, 53.28, 60.4, 61.050000000000004, 66.49, 60.72, 57.42, 61.29, 61.1, 57.52, 52.480000000000004, 52.17, 60.49, 54.77, 50.13, 51.4, 48.27, 45.24, 57.27, 61.02, 51.24, 53.980000000000004, 59.46, 52.82, 62.01, 52.65, 60.03, 56.27, 60.2, 58.45, 60.64, 53.56, 51.78, 57.22, 60.61, 54.82, 50.17, 55.0, 61.19, 57.06, 58.33, 54.61, 56.14, 52.03, 60.42, 53.85, 53.32, 47.18, 49.38, 61.03, 65.72, 55.08, 55.46, 58.5, 62.42, 55.910000000000004, 61.120000000000005, 52.980000000000004, 60.08, 54.45, 57.29, 57.89, 56.95, 55.58, 50.27, 50.620000000000005, 57.83, 59.120000000000005, 56.92, 58.95, 52.81, 55.58, 50.7, 56.75, 67.28, 55.0, 52.46, 64.34, 48.910000000000004, 51.57, 48.64, 46.57, 52.74, 58.410000000000004, 55.99, 55.68, 59.43, 64.32000000000001, 55.01, 46.18, 56.88, 50.83, 54.49, 63.18, 55.99, 58.34, 60.870000000000005, 54.94, 56.29, 61.54, 54.72, 65.28, 59.71, 55.44, 68.29, 47.95, 60.49, 54.27, 54.28, 51.31, 59.800000000000004, 57.07, 58.34, 53.93, 54.84, 59.84, 47.69, 45.94, 61.93, 59.17, 52.15, 54.28, 60.13, 51.44, 53.03, 65.43, 57.300000000000004, 60.29, 60.11, 53.34, 54.39, 57.870000000000005, 58.45, 57.86, 58.2, 60.2, 62.22, 52.81, 41.34, 55.01, 57.26, 62.09, 55.15, 56.11, 50.24, 47.93, 57.17, 54.14, 54.6, 51.84, 54.42, 56.27, 57.32, 61.11, 60.730000000000004, 56.370000000000005, 56.72, 71.25, 56.35, 55.6, 58.410000000000004, 48.89, 66.65, 64.17, 56.17, 62.980000000000004, 54.800000000000004, 51.49, 59.660000000000004, 63.67, 53.17, 63.49, 56.97, 53.56, 51.64, 53.74, 51.35, 54.730000000000004, 53.160000000000004, 60.46, 49.370000000000005, 54.63, 54.07, 51.2, 54.31, 48.54, 56.18, 47.94, 50.11, 58.88, 56.76, 55.870000000000005, 54.01, 61.79, 54.300000000000004, 66.12, 55.15, 51.2, 52.56, 54.980000000000004, 56.800000000000004, 45.82, 52.54, 56.77, 55.44, 52.050000000000004, 57.660000000000004, 52.11, 59.24, 52.120000000000005, 56.76, 54.11, 52.25, 58.28, 71.75, 58.51, 62.910000000000004, 60.72, 51.18, 56.49, 56.76, 55.59, 52.86, 49.26, 46.94, 57.99, 62.47, 55.550000000000004, 56.49, 59.14, 59.7, 58.74, 54.78, 74.86, 49.84, 56.44, 51.6, 57.31, 58.35, 53.21, 57.82, 49.1, 57.96, 52.160000000000004, 59.95, 49.9, 64.45, 55.69, 44.7, 60.480000000000004, 64.53, 53.120000000000005, 50.02, 60.24, 59.92, 60.71, 49.93, 56.94, 44.72, 59.910000000000004, 54.050000000000004, 55.730000000000004, 50.6, 60.160000000000004, 56.81, 57.08, 56.06, 64.78, 48.21, 48.43, 50.58, 56.08, 58.21, 50.2, 50.160000000000004, 55.870000000000005, 57.870000000000005, 57.46, 55.93, 52.25, 53.4, 48.0, 56.88, 50.21, 50.730000000000004, 52.38, 55.68, 63.11, 47.18, 66.24, 63.89, 56.43, 59.15, 53.56, 55.6, 60.86, 53.39, 57.95, 54.45, 53.370000000000005, 57.54, 56.2, 52.69, 53.43, 57.300000000000004, 50.85, 55.53, 51.410000000000004, 55.92, 56.15, 59.97, 54.86, 62.15, 56.07, 58.17, 53.04, 58.46, 57.74, 56.45, 64.84, 56.160000000000004, 49.050000000000004, 53.76, 58.36, 60.480000000000004, 59.15, 61.25, 53.58, 64.2, 69.15, 58.93, 52.86, 51.1, 63.35, 55.44, 63.77, 52.730000000000004, 49.21, 56.800000000000004, 50.53, 53.34, 53.44, 54.07, 60.54, 47.13, 52.34, 63.97, 55.97, 60.5, 62.38, 52.61, 49.97, 58.29, 58.06, 49.75, 49.160000000000004, 57.21, 54.24, 55.75, 56.13, 59.7, 49.050000000000004, 60.39, 57.53, 53.38, 55.410000000000004, 54.97, 63.58, 54.76, 59.910000000000004, 51.14, 49.35, 56.44, 53.550000000000004, 53.120000000000005, 57.72, 58.68, 59.74, 59.86, 55.39, 47.39, 52.47, 63.64, 59.76, 53.15, 54.980000000000004, 53.480000000000004, 59.79, 48.6], [1, 531]}

The schema of the dataframe is as follows:

```
root
 |-- Values: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- elements: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- dimensions: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
 |-- Column: long (nullable = true)
```

And I'm not very sure of how I should work with this data (is it a dictionary, but without keys?).

In the end, I would like that in the column 'Values', the only value that appears is the one in position 1 of the first array of the dictionary. So in the end, my dataframe should look like this:

| Values | Column |
| --- | --- |
| 54.04 | Sector A |
| 55.4800000 | Sector A |

Could someone please give me a hand to do this?

Comment: What is the schema of this df? What is the type of column ```Values```?

Comment: Hi. I just added the schema of the dataframe in the main post.

Comment: This seems to be a JSON structure, but the one you pasted is not valid

Comment: What do you mean it's not valid?

Comment: Can you check if this works-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72809356/extract-json-data-inside-array-to-rows-in-spark/72812533#72812533

Comment: I'm not sure about the data structure. If it is a struct, you should be able to do f.col("Values.elements") and then use `element_at` to get the first value. But your output doesn't show those keys... Can you post some code how to create an example DataFrame with the same structure?

Comment: @RvdV Hi, sorry for the late reply. I think posting the code won't help, what I am doing is just reading some parameters from a database, and they happen to have that 'structure'.

Comment: I don't think we need the code getting it from the database, but some code that reproduces the same schema. It looks like some multidimensional array, but I can't reproduce the example structure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And I'm not very sure of how I should work with this data (is it a dictionary, but without keys?).

Since this column is of struct type, you should work with it like with struct. It's not a dictionary (in Spark terminology, map type is closest to dictionary - it has both keys and values). But struct has similarities to dictionary too. Struct, instead of keys has fields. And fields can be of any other Spark data type (including struct itself).

To access fields inside struct you chain field name, like `Values.elements`. Then you do whatever the accessed data type requires. When you enter `Values.elements`, you have array type. So you must access its elements by index number. Putting it to code, it could look like this: `F.col('Values.elements')[1]`

Example dataframe:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(([0.0, 54.04   ], [1, 5]), 'Sector A'),
     (([0.0, 55.48000], [1, 4]), 'Sector A')],
    'Values:struct<elements:array<double>,dimensions:array<int>>, Column:string')
df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- Values: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- elements: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
#  |    |-- dimensions: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
#  |-- Column: string (nullable = true)
```

Script:

```py
df = df.select(
    F.col('Values.elements')[1].alias('Values'),
    'Column'
)

df.show()
# +------+--------+
# |Values|  Column|
# +------+--------+
# | 54.04|Sector A|
# | 55.48|Sector A|
# +------+--------+
```

Comment: Hi, I tried doing this but I get the following error: 
```
AnalysisException: Field name should be String Literal, but it's 1
```

Comment: I can replicate the error if I use `F.col('Values')[1].alias('Values'),` . But it's not what I wrote in the answer. Make sure you add field name `elements`, i.e. do it like in the answer: `F.col('Values.elements')[1].alias('Values'),`

Comment: You were right, that was the mistake! Thank you very much!!